# Call HLSL shader function from C# - Unity Engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl

I created a vertex shader which renders a displaced mesh by stacking Sine and Gerstner waves. To make the displacement in the shader interactable with my scene I made a C# script which does the exact same calculations. I would like to eliminate this, to prevent a desync in time.

**Is there a known way to call a HLSL function from a C# script?**

The function I would like to call is displayed here:

```
void GetWaveDisplacement_float(float3 vertex_in, out float3 out_pos, out float3 out_norm, out float out_y_offset)
{
    // Stacks wavecalculations at position "vertex_in" and returns the displaced position and the normal for this position
    float3 tangent = float3(1,0,0);
    float3 binormal =  float3(0,0,1);
    float3 p = float3(vertex_in.x, _YOffset, vertex_in.z);
    for (int i = 0; i < _GerstnerAmount; i++)
        p += GerstnerWave(_GerstnerWaves[i], vertex_in, tangent, binormal);
    for (int i = 0; i < _SineAmount; i++)
        p += SineWave(_SineWaves[i], vertex_in, tangent, binormal);
    for (int i = 0; i < _ImpactAmount; i++)
        p += ImpactWave(_ImpactWaves[i], vertex_in, _ImpactTimes[i], tangent, binormal);
    float3 normal = normalize(cross(binormal, tangent));
    out_pos = p;
    out_norm = normal;
    out_y_offset = _YOffset;
}
```

This function is part of a HLSL script which and gets called by a ShaderGraph Shader for all vertices.

The current code does the same calculations on the CPU using C# and syncing the CPU Time.time with the GPU every frame. Which is not always 100% accurate

A second option I am looking into is creating a float4[] array in HLSL which can be updated by the CPU with the points I need the displacement vector and normal for.

- This would be an asynchronous way to do it
- The float4[] needs to have a fixed size in HLSL which is means I would not be able to size the application dynamically.
- The displacement for these points would be calculated every pass of the shader

Comment: might want to checkout [ComputeShaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ComputeShader.html)